# Java - reading audio from TargetDataLine - reads only zeroes/

Tags: java, audio

I'm having trouble with TargetDataLine - it keeps reading only zeroes from the mixer.

The following is using arecord which works perfectly:

`arecord -D plughw:1,0,0 -r 44100  -f s16_le -c 2  -d 3 /tmp/file.wav`

When I try this with javax.sound.sampled, I keep getting zeroes.  The following opens the TargetDataLine with a thread to stop the reading after 5 seconds.  the read buffer is consistently filled with zeroes.

```
package com.example;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer.Info;

public class AudioTest {
    
    static final long RECORD_TIME = 5000; 
    private TargetDataLine line;
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    
    private void run() {

        Thread stopper = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(RECORD_TIME);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("\nSleep for " + RECORD_TIME + " complete - attempting to end");
                finish();
            }
        });
        
        stopper.start();
        
        try {
            AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100, 16, 2, true, false);
            
            Info[] infos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
            
            int mixerNumber = 3;  // This is the one that matches the one that works with arecord.
            
            Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(infos[mixerNumber]);
            
            System.out.println("Using infos " + mixerNumber + ", " + infos[mixerNumber].getName() + ", " +infos[mixerNumber].getDescription());
            System.out.println("Using format to open TargetDataLine: " + format.toString());
            
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
 
            line = (TargetDataLine)mixer.getLine(info);
             
             int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
             byte[] bytesBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
             int bytesRead = -1;
             
             line.open(format);
             isRecording = true;

             while (((bytesRead = line.read(bytesBuffer, 0 , BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) && (isRecording)) {
                 
                 if (bytesRead != 0)
                     System.out.println("Read Something - yeah");
             }
             
             System.out.println("");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private void finish() {
        line.stop();
        line.close();
        isRecording = false;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AudioTest audioTest = new AudioTest();
        audioTest.run();
    }
    
}
```

The output typically looks like this:

```
Using infos 3, Loopback [plughw:1,0], Direct Audio Device: Loopback, Loopback PCM, Loopback PCM
Using format to open TargetDataLine: PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian
Sleep for 5000 complete - attempting to end
logout
```

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing - thanks

Comment: Does your console display many "Read something - yeah" messages? In 5 seconds, I'm thinking you should get over 400 of them.

Comment: The method you use to specify your TargetDataLine--maybe a simpler form work?  `TargetDataLine tdl = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(audioFormat, mixerInfo);` where mixerInfo is the specific source you want to record from?

Comment: One last idea, instead of testing for -1 as a return value (would a microphone ever return -1? is your input a finite-length file?), put an instance boolean "isRunning" in the while loop test and have your timing thread set "isRunning" to false to stop the recording. Maybe one of these ideas will help. I've only implemented a basic TargetDataLine microphone recorder once and these ideas reflect some of the differences in how I implemented it compared to what you have. Having only done it once, I certainly don't claim expertise.